# Nested Dialog Input

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

I have a blocking Dialog that is taking input from another dialog internally. This is how I have coded

```
DialogInput[DynamicModule[{name},
  Button["Y", (name = DialogInput[InputField[]]), Method -> "Queued"]
  ]]
```

But the inner Dialog never appears after pressing Y button. If I use preemptive method then it shows

> DialogInput::nprmtv: DialogInput is not currently supported within
>   preemptive evaluations.

How can I open an inner DialogInput from an outer DialogInput ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it is not possible until you close the first one. But maybe you can get away by using something like: `DialogInput[DynamicModule[{x = 1}, Column[{
    Dynamic[x],
    Button[
     "adjust x", (CreateDialog[
       DynamicModule[{}, 
        Column[{Slider@Dynamic@x, Dynamic[x], 
          DefaultButton[NotebookClose[]]}], InheritScope -> True]])],
    DefaultButton["DialogReturn", DialogReturn[x]]
    }]
  ]
 ]` let me know if this fits your needs.

Comment: It was asked before: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111651/5478 but also iwthout a general solution.